# How can I add different listener for same movieClip in a loop in as3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I am trying to coding a part of a program which is creating different listener for the same object by using a for, but the problem is that the result for all of them is the same, In the following you can find my code:

```
for( var i:int=0;i<10;i++){


    var obj =  new MyClass();
    obj.y = i*30;


    obj.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, function(e:MouseEvent){
        value = i.toString();
        trace(value);
    });

    myOtherMovieClip.addChild(obj);
}
```

My goal of writing the code above is, by clicking on the first obj, the program writes 0 in output, by clicking on second one, writes 1 and so on, but this code give me 10 for all the objects.

I should add that no matter there is an obj or not in myOtherMovieClip area, by clicking in that area, I got the same value.

Any idea will be appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to achieve this is to set a value property to the `MyClass` object.

Or, techinically, if the `y` property is constant you could do:

```
var value:String = (e.target.y / 30).toString();
```

Comment: Thanks for your brilliant answer, that should be correct, but in my case I have myOtherMovieClip.addchild(obj) (I am going to edit question) and I do not know why I can click in area of this movieClip, don't matter there is the obj or not, and all the time I get the same result.

Comment: You get the same set value because `i` at the end of the loop is 10. So, your `i.toString()` returns 10.

Answer (score 1):

In order to directly solve your problem you could do that :

```
obj.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, function():Function{
    var value : String = i.toString();
    var listener : Function = function(e:MouseEvent):void{
        trace(value);
    }       
    return listener;
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple fix. Id your object.
Of course id will have to be a property on MyClass

```
for( var i:int=0;i<10;i++){
  var obj =  new MyClass();
  obj.y = i*30;

  obj.id = 'someMC_' + i
  obj.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, function(e:MouseEvent){
    var aVar:Array = e.target.id.split('_')
    trace(aVar[1]);
  });
  myOtherMovieClip.addChild(obj);
}
```